# Detect backbutton of the browser before the route change

Tags: typescript, angular6

How to detect the backbutton of the browser before the route change in `Angular`,i used popstate.it detects after the route changes,i want to detect before the route change.Is that possible in Angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following method. Hope this would resolve your issue.

$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    //Open the modal
    $('my-modal').show();`enter code here`
});

$stateChangeStart is an event of angular ui router.

Comment: thanks!This is correct and it works but,i want this in angular?